# Contains и sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет!

Вопрос следующий:

Есть 2 таблицы sql. Пишу запрос T-SQL:

```
SELECT [dbo].[test].[name],
       [dbo].[test].[fname],
       [dbo].[test].[note]
FROM [dbo].[blacklist], [dbo].[test]
WHERE CONTAINS([dbo].[test].[note], [dbo].[blacklist].[word])
```

Данный запрос не работает. В синтаксисе функции CONTAINS() указано, что у 2-го параметра должны быть кавычки.

Как можно организовать проверку? По идее необходимо сравнивать в таблице **test** значения поля **note** со значениями полей **word** таблицы **blacklist**.

Comment: Кажется у вас не хватает оператора `JOIN`, и возможно вы путаете операторы `CONTAINS` и `LIKE`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Задача стоит сделать с использованием CONTAINS(). А с JOIN как это использовать?

Comment: из документации - `<simple_term> ::=   { word | "phrase" }`  что у вас там потенциально содержится в  `word` слова или фразы? аналогично с префиксной формой, если `*` используется, то в кавычках. Грубо гововря вам нужен `concat('"', word, '"')`

Comment: @tym32167 куда вы тут хотите добавить JOIN и зачем?

Comment: @teran, в word будут слова. в note - фразы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать либо переменную, либо константное выражение. Для поиска по значению из колонки другой таблицы contains не предназначена. Если прямо очень хочется, можно сделать курсор и покрутить цикл, но это будет очень медленно.